# Correct use of SQL server query using PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am using PHP and when I tried to use the following query on SQL Server, it gives me a syntax error saying there is an invalid use near the key word `WHERE`. If I don't use the `WHERE Status='Open'` part in my query, this works fine without any error. Does the SQL server considering `Status` or `Open` as keywords?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ElectronicShop ORDER BY Completed WHERE Status='Open'";
```

Error:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 156 [code] => 156 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'. ) )
```

Comment: Read some books about SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WHERE clause must be before the ORDER BY clause (with any database, this is not related to SQL Server).

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ElectronicShop WHERE Status='Open' ORDER BY Completed";
```

Comment: Unless you are using the Linq to Entities in .net ;-)

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for showing me with an example. Now it says, `The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator`. Should I cast the `Open` to something else?

Comment: Status type is Text ? Why are you using this type ? I would prefer nvarchar.